# How to create child process to execute a method in c#?

Tags: c#, libpcap, winpcap, child-process

I have got an logical bug from **winpcap** library in **reading file from offline dump file**.  In that they are not closing the file after reading. So i am getting  an exception that "failed to open the file" when    file count reaches 509.

I am using pcap.net library with c#. Here is my code

```
OfflinePacketDevice selectedDevice = new OfflinePacketDevice(filename);
PacketCommunicator communicator = selectedDevice.Open(65536,PacketDeviceOpenAttributes.Promiscuous,1000);    
communicator.ReceivePackets(0, DispatcherHandler);
communicator.Dispose();
```

Now i need to execute the above statements as a **child process** ,so i think i can avoid that exception by calling the child processs for each pcap file. But i don't know how to execute a metho as child process in c#. Can any one give me a solution for this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for the alleged WinPcap library bug, the program reading the dump file *is* calling `pcap_close()` after it reads the last packet of the file, right?  If not, the bug is in the program, not in WinPcap.  Even if so, the bug might be in pcap.net, not WinPcap.

Comment: Pcap.net calls **pcap_close()** in PacketCommunicator destructor. So  when communicators  dispose method invokes it calls  pcap_close(). But the file pointer won't get released with its **pcapDescriptor.PacketCommunicator::~PacketCommunicator() 
{
    pcap_close(_pcapDescriptor);
}**     . I think its a winpcap bug.

Comment: Looking at the source to WinPcap 4.1.2, I see no bug - `pcap_close()` calls `p->cleanup_op`, which is set by the `savefile.c` code to `sf_cleanup()`, which, *unless you happen to be reading from stdin*, which only happens if the file name is `"-"`, will call `fclose()` on the underlying `FILE *`.  Are you certain that the destructor is getting called?

Comment: I am not sure about that. And i coudn't compile Pcap.net source code to check the bug.

Comment: Make sure the destructor is getting called.  Hopefully the creators of Pcap.net didn't do something stupid such as relying 100% on garbage collection to release file descriptors, because the CLR garbage collector probably has *NO CLUE* that it might need to garbage-collect  PacketCommunicator instances in order to free up file descriptors (or even just let files be renamed or removed, for example!).

Comment: I hope the fine folks who implemented Pcap.NET read [Cleaning Up Unmanaged Resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/498928w2.aspx) before implementing it; if not, and if they didn't just happen to do the right thing by accident, Pcap.NET is buggy, as pcap handles are *unmanaged* resources and you *cannot* rely on the garbage collector to handle them.